# how do I manipulate elements inside a xml in action script?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

What are the inbuilt functions available in flex,actionscript that I can use to find a node with a specific name inside xml variable and what functions could help me manipulate it? Something like Xquery in SQL! I dont want to use for loop everytime I want to manipulate a xml variable. For example, if I want to "cut" node inside this xml and add another attribute to it named enabled pro grammatically. Or how could I find "Find Next" node and delete it?

```
                 <menuitem label="Edit">
                    <m label="Cut"/>
                    <m label="Copy"/>
                    <m label="Paste"/>
                    <m type="separator"/>
                    <m label="Find"/>
                    <m label="Find Next"/>
                </menuitem>
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) *To find the "cut" node:*

There's an easy way to find the "cut" node, but it'll require you to remove the `<m type="separator" />` as it will throw an error with this code. To find it simply:

```
var cut:XMLList = xml.m.(@label == "Cut");
```

If you can't remove the "seperator" node, then you'll have to loop through to find it.

Once you have it, then to add a new attribute, it's simply:

```
cut.@someOther = true; // adds the attribute "someOther"
```

2) *Deleting the "Find Next" node*:

Deleting XML nodes in as3 is a bit awkward. You can try numerous ways, but you'll invariably end up with one error or another. See http://bottomupflash.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/deleting-xml-nodes-harder-than-it-looks/ for a bit more info.

The only piece of code that I could come up with that would delete the "Find Next" node is:

```
var i:int = 0;
for each( var x:XML in xml.m )
{
    if ( x.@label == "Find Next" )
        delete xml.m[i];
    i++;
}
```

Basically, we're looping through the structure, to find the index of the "Find Next" node, then we're deleting it using the child selector.

Comment: thanks divillysausages. It's a great help.  I will try these suggestions and see if they work alright (which I believe they should) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript supports [e4x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML). Also, read about [XML class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html).